# Creating and managing indexes in Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I am setting up indexes for my nodes and properties in Memgraph looking at the [documentation on indexes](https://memgraph.com/docs/fundamentals/indexes). I have two questions regarding the index management that I hope someone could help clarify:

1. Is it necessary to create the index only once or is there a need to recreate it under certain circumstances?
2. When executing the command `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE (n)`, which deletes all nodes and relationships, does this action also result in the deletion of the indexes, or are they preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to create indexes only once. You can use the [`SHOW INDEX INFO;` query](https://memgraph.com/docs/fundamentals/indexes#show-created-indexes) to check the existing indexes. If you are using Memgraph Lab, the information can be seen in the top bar.

Executing the `Match (n) detach delete (n)` query will not drop any indexes. The indexes remain intact even after deleting all nodes and relationships. To explicitly drop indexes you should [use the `DROP INDEX` query](https://memgraph.com/docs/fundamentals/indexes#delete-an-index).